# frmPING is a variable but is used like a type

Tags: c#, variables, types

Having an issue opening a new form, I get "'frmPING' is a variable but is used like a type" I've attached a screenshot and a snippet of my code.

I used this method to open new forms many times, infact I used it to get to this form. It's really driving me nuts

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOowG.png)

```
private void pingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               Form frmPING = new frmPING();
               frmPING.ShowDialog();

        }
```

Comment: Name the variable in a different way than the class name

Comment: Please start by reading the c# naming conventions on the MSDN. You will see the problem go away as you rename your objects

Comment: thanks @Steve i came right, turns out I was staring at the same problem for so long I hit full idiot, really appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to instanciate the form the wrong way. This would be the correct

```
   private void pingToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                   frmPING myForm = new frmPING();
                   myForm.ShowDialog();
            }
```